# How can I perform two operations inside a single map function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, puppeteer

I am currently trying to get all the trending repositories from Github's trending page and the stars they have and create a text file from it. URL is [this](https://github.com/trending)

I'm using Puppeteer for the same.

For the list of the repositories I did this

```
const data = await page.evaluate(()=>{
        const tds =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.explore-content ol li div h3'));
        return tds.map(td => td.textContent);
    });
```

which gives me the result like this

```
The top repositories are 

    charlax / professional-programming
,

    ssloy / tinyraytracer
,

    komeiji-satori / Dress
,

    ForrestKnight / open-source-cs
,

    hjacobs / kubernetes-failure-stories
,

    osforscience / deep-learning-ocean
,

    alexkimxyz / nsfw_data_scrapper
,

    kamranahmedse / developer-roadmap
,

    typescript-eslint / typescript-eslint
,

    Musish / Musish
,

    MisterBooo / LeetCodeAnimation
,

    yagiz / Bagel
,

    SpaceVim / SpaceVim
,

    antonmedv / fx
,

    pjialin / py12306
,

    braver / programmingfonts
,

    macrozheng / mall
,

    Snailclimb / JavaGuide
,

    schollz / howmanypeoplearearound
,

    flutterchina / flutter-in-action
,

    flutter / flutter
,

    rikschennink / shiny
,

    doocs / advanced-java
,

    MFatihMAR / Awesome-Game-Networking
,

    go-task / task
```

To get the stars, I have another function like this

```
const stars = await page.evaluate(()=>{
        const stars = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.explore-content ol li div:nth-child(4) a'));
        return stars.map(star=>star.textContent);

    });
```

which outputs in this way

The top repoitories have

```
    5,304
  ,

    379
  ,
          ,,,,,,

    1,173
  ,

    44
```

I want to combine the output of the two methods in a single method so that I can get the result as

> > charlax/professional-programming has 5,304 stars.

How can I combine the outputs of `data` and `stars` method or how can I do the two different operations in a single method. Can I perform two simulatenous operations inside a single `map` method? If so how?

Comment: Please share the dom

Comment: Are there always the same number of `stars` as `tds`?

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: Instead of using a map function , you should use for loop or forEach loop if here are same number of stars and tds

Comment: @brk you can find the DOM in the URL.

Comment: @Justcode formatted. I have added the output as is printed in the console. That's why there are a couple of delimiters like `'''` in the output.

Comment: @KomalBansal why and what is the advantage of using a forEach?

Comment: I would like to know why the downvote?

Comment: @demouser123 You can do mutiple things in the same loop

Comment: You can see me answer for the reference @demouser123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a safer way to do this:

```js
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const exctactedData = [];
  for (const entry of document.querySelectorAll('ol.repo-list > li')) {
    exctactedData.push(`${
      entry.querySelector('h3').innerText
    } has ${
      entry.querySelector('a[href$="/stargazers"]').innerText.trim()
    } stars.`);
  }
  return exctactedData.join('\n');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to "zip" the results of the two arrays and then map over that

```
await page.evaluate(()=>{
  const repos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.explore-content ol li div h3'));
  const stars = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.explore-content ol li div:nth-child(4) a'));

  // this is an array of tuples (two element arrays)
  // where the first element is the name and the second is the star count
  const zipped = repos.map((repoName, idx) => [repoName, stars[idx])

  return zipped.map(([repoName, starCount]) => `${repoName.textContent} ${starCount.textContent}`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. You dont have to await twice for the same thing.

```
const data = await page.evaluate(()=>{
  const stars = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.explore-content ol li div:nth-child(4) a'));
  const tds =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.explore-content ol li div h3'));
  var resArr = []
  for(let i = 0; i<stars.length; i++){
    resArr.push(`${tds[i].textContent} has ${stars[i].textContent}`)
  }
  return resArr;
}
```

Comment: How do you know `stars` & `tds` will have same length?

Comment: That's what we asked demouser123

Comment: Your answer assumes both have same length